# What is the difference or trade-off between returning void vs returning a linked-list when inserting a node?

Tags: c, data-structures

Let's say we have two functions that insert a node in the beginning:

This one returns the linked-list:

```
struct Node* insertFirst(struct Node *head, int data){
    struct Node *tmp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    tmp->data = data;
    tmp->next = head;
    return tmp;
}
```

This one returns void

```
void insertFirstVoid(struct Node **head, int data){
    struct Node *tmp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    tmp->data = data;
    tmp->next = *head;
    *head = tmp;
}
```

In the main we can use as follow:

```
int main(){
    struct Node *ptr0 = NULL;
    struct Node *ptr1 = NULL;
     
    // Insert and return the linked-list
    ptr0 = insertFirst(ptr0, 10);
    
    // Insert without returning
    insertFirstVoid(&ptr1, 10);
}
```

Comment: Try to rwrite the sine ( `sin()` ) function in both styles. What is the difference?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title question exhibits at least two misconceptions:

> What is the difference or trade-off between returning void vs returning a linked-list when inserting a node?

1. Neither version returns a linked list.  One version returns a pointer to (presumably) the head node of such a list, but that's not the same thing.
2. The key difference is not returning `Node *` *vs* returning `void`.  Rather, it is conveying the head pointer back to the caller via the function's return value *vs*. via an in/out argument.

Some of the main trade-offs are

- The version that accepts the head pointer directly and returns the new head pointer relies on the caller to do the right thing with the return value, whereas the version that handles the head pointer with an in/out argument permits the function to modify the caller's stored copy of the head node itself.  The former is therefore more prone to being used incorrectly.
- The in/out version, with its two levels of indirection, is a bit harder to read and understand, especially for less experienced programmers.  It is therefore somewhat more prone to attracting errors.

Overall, both ways work when implemented and used correctly, and both approaches are used in practice, though not usually in the same project.  It is unlikely that there is any significant performance difference.  Choose the one that suits you better, based on whatever criteria make sense to you, and move on.  There is no wrong choice here.